# How to Make a ComObject "internetexplorer.application" settings persist through new window navigation

Tags: powershell, explorer, citrix, persist, comobject

Within Citrix, we are calling a site by using the path as the PowerShell local path:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

And using The following command line argument:

```
. C:\Temp\IELockdown.ps1 -server https://www.server.com/app
```

The `IELockdown.ps1` contains the following code:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$server
)

$ieObject = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'

$ieObject.AddressBar = 0
$ieObject.StatusBar = 0
$ieObject.ToolBar = 0
$ieObject.MenuBar = 0

$ieObject.Navigate("$server")

$ieObject.Visible = 1
```

This lockdown code gets rid of the menu bar, status bar, address bar, and toolbar for the end user. This works fine for the first launch, but  The problem I am having is when the users are using our application, they click on a link that opens a new IE window. The new IE window has the address bar, menu bar, toolbar etc. visible.

The script is supposed to get rid of this, but it doesn't persist between windows. I have searched but can't currently find a solution for this. Is there any way to get this lockdown for IE to persist for the entire Citrix session or through new open windows, not just the first time the site is opened?

Comment: I don't think that your lockdown.ps script can help you here... Did you check, if it is possible with group policies? Or maybe check if the "Content Advisor" can help you.